# Exclude mySite from URL detector with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex (in javascript) for detect any URL but not the ones contains "mysite" (aka 'example' because the stackoverflow filter) in the domain.

`(?<protocol>\w+s?:\/\/)?(?<subdomain>\w+\.)(?<domain>(?!example)(\w+))(?<tls>\.\w{2,4})(?<querystring>\/.*)?\S*`

- ?protocol to detect the protocol of the URL (http, https, ftp etc...
- ?subdomain to detect any subdomain
- ?domain to detect any domain (here is where i want to exclude mysite)
- ?tls to detect .com, .org etc...
- ?querystring to detect the rest of the URL

Examples:

```
No detected
https://www.example.org/hello?
http://www.example.org/hello
https://blog.example.org/hello? 
example.org
www.example.org

Detected
www.example.org
www.www.example.org
example.org
```

[You can see this regex and examples on regex101 here](https://regex101.com/r/mKbfQk/1)

Comment: Whats your exact issue? Although I can guess you also want to discard `http://www.aaamysiteaaa.com/hello`. Is that correct?

Comment: 'mySite' is a example for the name of my web, i just want to discard just the format ```www.mysite.com``` not that example you say because that example I want to be detected with the regex.

Comment: Ok so you want to discard only and only if the domain name is `www.mysite.com` and rest you want to allow. E.g. you want to allow `www.mysite123.com`. Is that correct? It is a little confusing as to what you want to allow and what not. Can you add some allowed and not-allowed samples? That would help

Comment: What you say is correct, i just added a examples on the post but with the name 'example' because the stackoverflow filter for URLs

Comment: I think you are just missing a `?` after `(?<subdomain>\w+\.)` in your regex as you want to make subdomain also optional. Just add `?` after `(?<subdomain>\w+\.)` and it should work like you want.

Comment: Yes, i try that and the regex just detect all the examples on the link, i want to the regex ignore all the strings who contains "mysite"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed with you, there were several things to be taken care. Mentioning some of them below,

- Domain level group needed a `*` as you wanted to allow it zero or more times.
- Enclosing it in word boundary was needed to disallow it matching partially in the text.
- `.*` in the end of regex was needed to be replaced by `\S*` to avoid matching any whitespace in the URL

With these changes your updated and working regex becomes this,

```
\b(?<protocol>\w+s?:\/\/)?(?<subdomain>\w+\.)*(?<domain>(?!mysite)(\w+))(?<tls>\.\w{2,4})(?<querystring>\/\S*)?\b
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mKbfQk/7)**